how do i get my docker to play nice with Iris(R) Xe graphics gpus
I have a t29 lenovo with
glxinfo responds with
D3D12 (Intel(R) Iris(R) Xe Graphics)

I am running windows 11 pro, with WSL2 ubuntu.
My docker desktop is shared on WSL ubuntu in the settings
My ubuntu docker is working
My Windows docker is working .. i.e. when I run docker run hello-world it runs fine.

I am running
docker run --gpus all -it ollama/ollama

The response I get is:
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error running hook #0: error running hook: exit status 1, stdout: , stderr: Auto-detected mode as 'legacy'
nvidia-container-cli: initialization error: WSL environment detected but no adapters were found: unknown.

and in WSL2 ubuntu I get the same thing:
$ docker run --gpus all -it ollama/ollama
Response is:
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error running hook #0: error running hook: exit status 1, stdout: , stderr: Auto-detected mode as 'legacy'
nvidia-container-cli: initialization error: WSL environment detected but no adapters were found: unknown.

For some reason it want to run nvidia ...

You pasted the error message in Command Prompt and tried to run it. This will obviously not work. What is your actual Docker invocation? What do you mean by point 2, “My docker desktop is shared…”? What do you mean by point 4, “My Windows docker is working”?

@DanielB I edited the question
regarding dockerdesktop is shared, means it is passing its credentials to the WSL

GPU support in Docker Desktop is only available for NVIDIA GPUs. You cannot use it with an Intel GPU. Remove --gpus all from the Docker invocation.
It is unclear whether Ollama supports Intel GPUs at all. Because their capabilities are so limited, they probably aren’t of much interest to the AI/machine learning community.
WSL 2 itself apparently could support GPU virtualization with Intel GPUs. Make sure you are running the latest drivers. You could then install Docker inside your WSL 2 distribution and that has a better chance of working. I haven’t found concrete evidence though.
